# Is there a way to get safe addresses associated with an owner address?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to use Gnosis safe core sdk(https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk) to build an application.

Once application is connected to a user through metamask, is there a way to fetch safe addresses associated with that owner's wallet?

Comment: You'd need a [subgraph](thegraph.com) which indexes the events emitted by the Gnosis Safe factory contract.

Comment: Thanks @PaulRazvanBerg Would this help in getting historical safe addresses? For example, a user created safe directly from gnosis safe website and then when that same user connects with application created by me, it would be able fetch safe address created by that user.

Comment: Yes, it depends on how you'd write the subgraph, but that is doable.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction service indexes Safe <> owner relationships. You could use an endpoint there to fetch the Safes an address is owner of: https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/api/v1/owners/0x8fd960F1B9D68BAD2B97bD232FB75CC1f186B064/safes/

Full endpoint docs here: https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/ (endpoint is called `owners_safes_list`

Comment: Thanks @tschubotz , but this does not work if one has to choose networks like Rinkeby etc. Another one i found was one which was working in that case: https://safe-client.gnosis.io/v1/chains/4/owners/{ownerAddress}/safes